# endfloat and ctable are incompatible?

Tags: tables, packages, incompatibility, ctable, endfloat

It seems that `endfloat` and `ctable` are [incompatible](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/latexusersgroup/LWN_8lrJA_w):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{endfloat}
\usepackage{ctable}
\begin{document}

\ctable[caption = Queries available, pos = H, center, botcap]{ll}
{% notes
}
{% rows
\FL
search ``by='' & purpose
\ML
abstract & search terms in the publication abstract
\\\noalign{\medskip}
author & match authors in the publication
\\\noalign{\medskip}
id.taxon & Taxon identifier number from TreeBase
\\\noalign{\medskip}
tree & The title for the tree
\LL
}
```

Gives the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\\  ->\let \reserved@e 
                       \relax \let \reserved@f \relax \@ifstar {\let \reserv...
l.21 }
```

Is there any way to work around this problem?  Either

1. an alternative to `endfloat` that works for `ctable`,
2. or at least a way to make `endfloat` ignore the `ctable` instead of error?

#### Edit:

I'm looking for a solution that still uses `ctable` for the table.  Ideally some option that I can set in the preamble to resolve the conflict, or create `endfloat`-style behavior without the `endfloat` package?  (Editing the table itself isn't in the spirit of the `endfloat` package, since I could equally well move the table to the end manually, but that is not a good programmatic solution to apply over many documents.)

Comment: 8.1 of endfloat docs says: "as stated in sec 10.3, endfloat will utterly fail if one does something like `\newenvironment{foo}{...\begin{table}...}{...\end{table}...}`; there's a command `\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor` ...; ctable does exactly that embedding game, so `\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{ctable}{table}` may solve your problem.

Comment: hmm, thanks for the hint... I tried adding `\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{ctable}{table}` to the preamble, which results in a different error: `Runaway argument? ! File ended while scanning use of \efloat@xfloat.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about alternatives to `endfloat`, but there's a pretty good alternative to `ctable`: the "regular" `table` and `tabular` environments, combined with the commands of the `booktabs` package. (Replace the `\FL`, `\ML`, and `\LL` macros with `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule`, and you're mostly done converting the `ctable`. The similarity between the types of horizontal lines is of course anything but coincidental, given that `ctable` uses the `bookstabs` package internally.)

The following MWE produces a table that looks pretty much like the one your code produces, while being fully compatible with `endfloat`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{endfloat,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.35} % vary this to suit your needs
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
search ``by='' & purpose\\
\midrule
abstract & search terms in the publication abstract\\
author   & match authors in the publication\\
id.taxon & Taxon identifier number from TreeBase\\
tree     & The title for the tree\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Queries available}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm only using ctable because it is the only option provided by pandoc. Sadly not a viable solution for this particular project.

Comment: Just to be clear -- [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) generates LaTeX code from other input sources; a markdown table in my case, but for some reason I do not understand chooses to use the ctable environment rather then the standard table environment.  As such, I'm looking for a programmatic solution that can be accomplished by changing the preamble text, rather than changing the content of the ctable table itself.  My apologies for not stating this in the original question.

Comment: @cboettig -- Thanks for providing these additional explanations. I must confess I don't understand the innnards of the `ctable` package enough to provide additional suggestions on how you might be able to get it to work with `endfloat`. Your best bet may be to send an email message to the author/maintainer of the `ctable` package and ask for help, suggestions, or (depending on the cause of the problems) a bug fix.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Though this doesn't solve my particular use case, since I have to use ctable in this context, avoiding ctable when possible & writing to the package maintainers seems the best advice, so I accept the answer.